# Run NLP-based search and replace on Latex files

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a handful of Latex documents which mainly contain plain English text, with a little Latex commands, e.g. `\footnote`, `\cite`.

With **spacy** in Python, I have managed to run NLP on the files and analyze something.

Right now, I got a new requirement that rather than merely searching, I need to replace and save back the file.

I have 10+ keyword/replacement pairs. For example, if a word lemma is "report" and part of speech is verb, I have to surround it with `\it{}` (a Latex command). Don't do this with "report" whose part of speech is noun.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = ...

text = removeLatexComments(text)
text = removeSectionHeadings(text)
# remove latex commands
text = re.sub(r'\\\w+\{(.+)\}', '', text)

doc = nlp(text)

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'LEMMA': 'report'}, {'POS': 'verb'}]
matches = matcher(doc)
for m in matches:
    print("Found {}".format(doc[m[1]:m[2]]))
```

The code is what I have right now. I'm able to check if there are noun "report". Then How do I run a replace and save it back?

Moreover, I have removed section headings and uninteresting Latex commands, but I have to keep them when I write my file back. Are there any tools to help me this?

I feel it's like Antlr4's rewriter... but introducing Antlr might be too laborious.